# How to record system sound without video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I installed [Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower) with `brew cask install soundflower` and I see it listed:

```
$ ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f9a32515e80] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f9a32515e80] [0] FaceTime HD Camera
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f9a32515e80] [1] Capture screen 0
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f9a32515e80] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f9a32515e80] [0] Soundflower (2ch)
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f9a32515e80] [1] Built-in Microphone
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7f9a32515e80] [2] Soundflower (64ch)
```

I found several threads on recording the screen without system sound ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590500/ffmpeg-record-output-audio-for-mac), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828236/how-to-record-audio-with-ffmpeg-on-linux), [three](https://superuser.com/questions/1154806/how-can-i-record-audio-from-the-microphone-with-ffmpeg)) and one about [recording audio on Linux with ALSA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682144/capturing-only-desktop-audio-with-ffmpeg). I could not find how to record audio only, without video.

I also tried this command to record the audio along with the screen `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "1:0" ~/Downloads/Screen.mov`, and I got an error `Conversion failed!`.

How can I record system sound to a file with FFMPEG?

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":0" output.wav`. If it fails provide the complete log.

Comment: Yes, it worked, and it was that simple. Can you write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `1:0` you're including the video input from *FaceTime HD Camera*. Try:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":0" output.wav
```

This only selects audio device `0` which is *Soundflower (2ch)*.

See [avfoundation input device documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#avfoundation) for more info.